# Get posts count inside WooCommerce product category page loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, count, global

I'm trying to get the posts count inside my product category page loop (Woocommerce), but it just doesn't work. Does anyone knows why?

Woocommerce uses the same file archive-product.php for displaying both Shop Page and Product Category Page. In my archive-product.php, I passed the value to a variable using a Woocommerce function before the loop starts:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );

$totalproducts = wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' );

woocommerce_product_loop_start();

if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product') );
    }
}

woocommerce_product_loop_end();
```

Inside the content-product.php, I call the variable and then I use it to add an inline z-index to each post, decreasing it at each post.

```
<?php global $totalproducts; ?>

<div class="product-item" style="z-index: <?php echo $totalproducts; ?>;">
   content of the post
</div>

<?php $totalproducts = $totalproducts - 1; ?>
```

For the Shop Page it works perfectly, but for the Product Categories pages it just doesn't work, the variable comes empty. If I echo the variable before the loop starts in my archive-product.php it shows the post count from the category, so it's working fine for both pages. But I just can't get the variable inside the loop, specifically in the Categories Pages. Does anyone knows why this is happening?

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally found a solution for my problem.

What I did was adapting my code and create the woocommerce.php in my theme's directory instead of overriding the archive-product.php.

And then the file finally got the variable for the product category pages too.
I have no idea of why this happened.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe using the global variable `$wp_query` and its property `post_count`, replacing in your code:

```
$totalproducts = wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' );
```

by this:

```
global $wp_query;

$totalproducts = wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ? wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) : $wp_query->post_count;
```

It could better work.

---

Also you can simplify this line:

```
<?php $totalproducts = $totalproducts - 1; ?>
```

by:

```
<?php $totalproducts--; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried with $wp_query but it didn't work :( I also tried with get_queried_object() + get_terms() and it didn't work too...